# How have I got a static IP address?

Tags: networking, server

I'm having some difficulty with bridging in KVM, while trying to sort it out I have noticed something strange, My server has always had the IP address 192.168.1.140, this persists when i reboot, always.

Yet when in `/etc/network/interfaces`
i notice that is is set up:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

So is there somewhere else that this ip address could have been assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Your KVM host is probably running the libvirt-bin service (the default Ubuntu way of running KVM guests). This service runs a dnsmasq instance for the `virbr0` interface (default network configuration for libvirt). Dnsmasq is a service to provide DHCP and basic DNS recursion. So, basically, your KVM host is running a 'simple' DHCP server for the KVM guests in the virtual network named `default` (by default). In virt-manager it looks like this:

[image]

- Firstly, dnsmasq will 'cache' the DHCP leases provided to clients (KVM guest in your case). So if a client asks for an IP again before the lease is expired, it will be assigned with the same one as before. This assignment is based on the MAC address of the client. The MAC address of the virtual network card of the KVM guest is set when you create/define a KVM guest with a network interface (or add an interface to an existing guest).
- Secondly, your DHCP client caches the previous lease and in successive DHCP requests it will ask for the IP it got before (which will probably be honoured if the DHCP server client IP pool isn't exhausted).

Comment: I perhaps should have left the KVM bit out of my question, I think the KVM issue can be disregarded, the /etc/network/interfaces was this before kvm and is this now, yet i always have the ip address of 192.168.1.140 on the *host*